# using LEFT JOIN and LIKE mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a problem in mysql query.
this is how my tables looks like:

```
mysql> select username, specialty from users;
+----------+------------------+
| username | specialty        |
+----------+------------------+
| JinkX    | php, html, mysql |
| test1    | html             |
+----------+------------------+


mysql> select name, tags from tasks;
+----------------+------+
| name           | tags |
+----------------+------+
| fix front page | html |
+----------------+------+
```

and when i try to do the following query, it works only if the specialty equals exactly the tags. but i want it to work on both

```
mysql> select tasks.name from users left join tasks on tasks.tags LIKE users.specialty where users.username = 'test1';
+----------------+
| name           |
+----------------+
| fix front page |
+----------------+

mysql> select tasks.name from users left join tasks on tasks.tags LIKE users.specialty where users.username = 'JinkX';
+------+
| name |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

Comment: Are you open to changing (normalising) the schema?

Comment: As per Joe's answer (though I'd probably have a separate `tags` table with an integer surrogate key). This will allow indexes to be used to make your queries more efficient (rather than having to scan every user record)

Comment: @Martin this is a very good idea actually, ill work on it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you've discovered the pain of saving independent values as a comma-delimited string.

If you can, I would suggest that you change your data structure, get the specialty column out of the user table, and create a new `user_specialty` table that would have foreign keys to `users.username` and `tasks.tags`.

```
+----------+------------------+
| username | tag              |
+----------+------------------+
| JinkX    | php              |
| JinkX    | html             |
| JinkX    | mysql            |
| test1    | html             |
+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

You're doing `like` wrong.

Try this query:

```
select tasks.name 
from users left join tasks on users.specialty LIKE CONCAT('%',tasks.tags,'%') 
where users.username = 'JinkX'
```

This is not the **best** way but it should work

EDIT: as per comments there's another way which should be better

Using REGEXP:

```
select tasks.name 
from users left join tasks on users.specialty REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,) ?',tasks.tags,' ?($|,)') 
where users.username = 'JinkX'
```

Comment: Not recommended.  This could create a false match if one tag is a subset of another.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `find_in_set` function.  Put this in your `where` clause:

```
FIND_IN_SET(task.tags,users.specialty)
```

[(Reference)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: What format does this expect? From the docs it looks like it would want the individual strings to be delimited? `'php', 'html', 'mysql'`

Comment: FIND_IN_SET does not expect strings to be delimited.  It looks only for the commas.  Not sure if it trims spaces or not; need to check that.